# How to create a better tables Structure

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

For my website i have tables

```
Category :: id | name
Product  :: id | name | categoryid
```

Now each category may have different sizes, for that I have also created a table

```
Size :: id | name | categoryid | price
```

Now the problem is that each category has also different ingredients that customer can choose to add to his purchased
product. And these ingredients have different prices for different sizes.
For that I also have a table like

```
Ingredient :: id | name | sizeid | categoryid | price
```

I am not sure if this Structure really normalized is. Can someone please help me to optimize this structure and which indexed do i need for this Structure?

Comment: It might be easier to see whether or not it is normalized if you provide a small amount of example data (e.g. between 2 and 5 example rows per table) that demonstrates how you will be using these tables in practice. This will make it easier to spot possible redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category :: id | name
Product  :: id | name | categoryid 
Size :: id | name |
Ingredient :: id | name |
Category_Size :: id | categoryid | SizeID | Price
Category_Ingredient :: id | categoryID | IngredientID | Price

All complex entities are broken into least possible parts (individual table). Then used foreign key relations to relate them logically.

Answer (score 1):

> And these ingredients have different prices for different sizes.

If an ingredient's price depends only on its size and not also the category then try this:

```
Ingredient :: id | name 

Ingredient_Price :: ingredientid | sizeid | price

Ingredient_Category :: ingredientid | categoryid
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain it a bit more, why it is better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user160820: I've separated the relationship between ingredients and categories from the relationship between the size of an ingredient and its price. This reduces redundancy if the price does not depend on the category. I also avoid duplicating the ingredient name, again reducing redundancy and preventing modification anomolies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies

Answer (score 0):

Structure look good to me. PK will be indexed by defining them as PK of course.
You need to add indexes for all FKs:

```
product.categoryId, 
size.categoryId, 
ingredient.categoryId, 
ingredient.sizeId
```

Depending on the size of your tables, and on the fact that you might want to display items alphabetically, you might also want to index all the name fields.